Counting birds outside my house
Outside your house there are a series of telephone wires, which birds like to perch on. They mostly sit still, but every so often a flock of them moves.
Flocks of birds follow a peculiar pattern of movement.

One flock of birds always moves at once. That is every bird in the flock moves, no bird not in the flock moves.
If a flock of \$k\$ birds moves, each bird in the flock moves \$k\$ poles down the telephone wire in the same direction (the flock as a whole may move either direction).

From your window you don't know which birds belong to which flocks, only how many birds there are between telephone poles. This can be represented as a list of non-negative integers.
Your task is to determine from a start and end state whether a single movement following the above description has taken place.
For example [1,0,1,1,0] -> [0,0,1,1,1] is a valid move. Below we show a flock of two birds separated from the remainder moving two poles down:
0 0 0 1 0 -> 0 0 0 1 0
1 0 1 0 0 -> 0 0 1 0 1

As another example [2,2,3,2] -> [3,2,2,2] is not a valid move. There must have been multiple flocks moving while you weren't looking for this pattern to happen.
A tricky example is [1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1] -> [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,0]. It looks like one bird has moved from the last position to the first position. However it could have actually been a flock of three birds moving three poles up:
1 2 2 1 2 2 1 2 2 0 -> 0 2 2 1 2 2 1 2 2 1
0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 -> 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0

I fear the birds may be learning to program, so as an obfuscation method I am making this a code-golf challenge. The goal is to minimize the size of your source code as measured in bytes.
IO
You will receive as input two lists of non-negative integers representing the before and after states. You may assume that the two lists are the same length.
You should choose two distinct values, and your program should output one of them when a single valid bird move could have been made, and the other when that would be impossible. If no change has occurred we can consider that a flock of size zero, and it is considered valid.
Test cases
Valid
[1,0,1,1,0] -> [0,0,1,1,1]
[1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1] -> [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,0]
[1,2,0,2,1] -> [1,2,0,2,1]
[2,3,2,2] -> [3,2,2,2]
[3,3,2,3,4] -> [4,5,2,2,2]

Invalid
[1] -> [0]
[2,2,3,2] -> [3,2,2,2]
[1,2,3,2] -> [2,1,2,3]
[8,9,9,9] -> [9,9,9,9]
[0,1,0,0] -> [0,0,0,0]
[1,0,0,0,0] -> [0,0,0,0,1]


JavaScript (Node.js), 119 bytes
a=>g=(b,r=n=(a.map((v,i)=>m+=(v-b[i])*i,m=0),m*m)**.25)=>a.some(u=>u<b[++i],i=-1)?b[i]--*a[i+m/n]--*g(b,r-1)>0:r+a==0+b

Try it online!
Although following algorithm passes all testcases, I have no idea if it actually works... (So use at your own risk)
Given \$\vec{a},\vec{b}\in\mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}^{n}\$ for number of birds After and Before. Let’s define \$\vec{u}=[0,1,\dots,n-1]^\top\$ and we need to move \$n\$ birds with \$d\$ cells where
$$
\begin{aligned}
m&=\left(\vec{a}-\vec{b}\right)\cdot\vec{u}\\
n&=\sqrt{\left|m\right|}\\
d&=\frac{m}{n}
\end{aligned}
$$
In each move, we find first \$i\$ such that \$a_i<b_i\$, and move one bird by \$b_{i}'=b_i-1\$, \$a_{i+d}'=a_{i+d}-1\$. The moving may fail if \$i+d\notin\{0,\dots,n-1\}\$ or \$a_{i+d}=0\$.
We would report false if either \$n\$ is not integer, or we failed to attempt \$n\$ moves, or \$\vec{a}'\neq\vec{b}'\$ after \$n\$ moves. Or true if we successfully make \$\vec{a}'=\vec{b}'\$ after \$n\$ moves.
The algorithm has \$\mathcal{O}\left(n^2\right)\$ time complexity. However, since the function is symmetric, you may swap \$\vec{a}\$ and \$\vec{b}\$ so \$d\ge 0\$. Then a improved implementation could do the process in \$\mathcal{O}\left(n\right)\$ time.

Fail [1],[0]

@l4m2 Fixed. ...

Charcoal, 57 bytes
≔Σ⊕⁺⌊θ⌈θη≔↔↨Ｅθ↨ιη±¹ζ⬤Ｅη⊖Ｘηι⎇κ∨﹪ζι∨⁻κΣ↨÷ζιη⊙⮌↨÷ζιη›λ§⮌⌊θμζ

Try it online! Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input as an array of two arrays and outputs an inverted Charcoal boolean, i.e. nothing if a single movement exists, - if not. Explanation:
≔Σ⊕⁺⌊θ⌈θη

Charcoal has no polynomials, so these are simulated by performing operations with an arbitrarily large base b, here computed as the sum of the incremented values in the input arrays.
≔↔↨Ｅθ↨ιη±¹ζ

Calculate the difference between the two arrays in base b.
⬤Ｅη⊖Ｘηι⎇κ∨﹪ζι∨⁻κΣ↨÷ζιη⊙⮌↨÷ζιη›λ§⮌⌊θμζ

If the difference is not zero, and no integer exists such that the difference is divisible by bⁿ-1, the result of the division being represented in base b with digits whose sum is n, and those digits do not exceed the corresponding value in the smaller of the two input arrays (e.g. in the last test case, a flock of size 2 cannot move since there are no birds in the middle of the array), then output a -.
45 42 bytes if I ever get around to implementing Cartesian product on ATO:
⊙Π⁺Ｅ⌈θ…·⁰ιＥ⌈θ⁰›⁼⌊θＥ⌈θ⁺⁻λ§ιμ§ι⁻μΣι⌊✂ι⁻Ｌ⌈θΣι

Attempt This Online? Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input as an array of two arrays and outputs a Charcoal boolean, i.e. - if a single movement exists, nothing if not. Explanation: For each possible flock, calculates whether it can legally move by its size k and if so whether that results in the other state.

Python3, 324 bytes
from itertools import*
R=range
def f(a,b):
 v=[*R(len(a))]
 for i in v:
  for j in combinations(v,i):
   for t in product(*[R(1,a[u]+1)for u in j]):
    for D in[1,-1]:
     F,O=1,[*a]
     for u,k in zip(j,t):
      if 0<=(T:=u+sum(t)*D)<len(O)and u<len(a)and O[u]:O[u]-=k;O[T]+=k
      else:F=0
     if F and O==b:return 1

Try it online!

JavaScript (Node.js), 103 bytes
f=(a,b,i=0)=>1/a[i]&&f(b,a,i+(a<=b))|![...a].map((t,j,a)=>s+=!(t-=b[j])||t<0&(a[i+j]+=t)>=0?t:f,s=i)==s

Try it online!
-1B Shaggy
Try all is and all (a,b) orders

Would 1/a[i]&& work instead of the ternary?

R, 179 bytes
\(i,f,s=1:length(i))any(apply(expand.grid(lapply(i,seq,f=0)),1,\(g,n=sum(g))any(sapply(c(-1,1),\(d)all(sapply(s,\(x)i[x]-g[x]+`if`((x+d*n)%in%s,g[x+d*n],0))==f)))))&sum(i)==sum(f)

Attempt This Online!
Commented:
# takes initial positions i and final positions f, calculates vector of poles s
function(i, f, s = 1:length(i)) {
  # iterates over all possible flocks and returns true if any are valid
  any(apply(
    expand.grid(lapply(i, seq, first = 0)), # all possible flocks (beginning position)
    1,
    function(g, n = sum(g)) { # n = size of flock
      # true for either direction -1 or 1:
      any(sapply(c(-1,1), function(d) {
        # true if new counts are same as final counts on every pole 
        all(sapply(s, function(x) {
          # initial count minus flock count on that pole
          i[x] - g[x] + 
            # plus new birds, if that doesn't go outside the listed poles
            if ((x+d*n) %in% s) g[x+d*n] else 0
        }) == f)
      }))
    }
  )) & 
  # check that the number of birds stays the same
  # necessary to make sure no birds flew outside of the listed poles
  sum(i)==sum(f) 
}


Jelly, 23 bytes
ṫS‘$+NS¬ȧƊ
ṂŻ€ŒpÇ€+Ʋe@Ṁ

A monadic Link that accepts a pair of lists of birds per pole and yields 1 if a flock of \$k \ge 0\$ birds could have moved in tandem by \$k\$ steps each to transition from one state to the other.
Try it online! Or see the test-suite.
How?
If a flock could have moved then it could have moved left from the minimum of the two states to the maximum of the two states.
If any flock movement would take any birds farther left than any of the poles that state change should not be considered.
ṫS‘$+NS¬ȧƊ - Link 1, Get Delta: Flock (same format as a State)
   $       - last two links as a monad - f(Flock):
 S         -   sum {Flock} -> FlockSize
  ‘        -   increment
ṫ          - tail {Flock} from {that} index
     N     - negate {Flock}
    +      - add these together -> PoleDeltas
         Ɗ - last three links as a monad - f(PoleDeltas):
      S    -   sum {PoleDeltas} -> 0 if birds stayed within range
       ¬   -   logical NOT
        ȧ  -   logical AND {PoleDeltas}

ṂŻ€ŒpÇ€+Ʋe@Ṁ - Main Link: States
Ṃ            - minimum {States} -> MinState
        Ʋ    - last four links as a monad - f(MinState):
 Ż€          -   zero-range each
   Œp        -   Cartesian product
                 -> all potential flocks (including [0,0,...])
     Ç€      -   call Link 1 for each -> ValidDeltas
       +     -   add {MinState} (vectorises)
                 -> PossibleNewStates
           Ṁ - maximum {States} -> MaxState
         e@  - {MaxState} exists in {PossibleNewStates}

